# What is the meaning of Rebecca Words?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In **[Ghost World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_World_%28film%29)**, Rebecca said these words after watching Joey McCobb TV Show, with Edin:

> Edin: If he's so weird, how come he's wearing Nikes? Joey McCobb is
>   our god.
>
> Rebecca: **I want to do him.**
>
> Edin: I bet.

What is the meaning of Rebecca Words?

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/350181/2303)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Do* can be a euphemism for sexual intercourse. This appears to be the intended meaning here, so it is equivalent to:

> I want to have sex with him.